# Create a barplot with unique strings

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization

```
#Data set
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
data <- data_frame(ended= c("14/11/2016 13:37", "14/11/2016 13:37",
"14/11/2016 13:47", "14/11/2016 13:51", "14/11/2016 13:51"), 
satisfactionLevel = c("Very dissatisfied", "Very satisfied",
"Satisfied", "Neither satisfied nor dissatisfied",
"Very satisfied"))
```

I want to make a barplot where the x axis contains the different satisfaction levels and y axis counts their number.

I tried

```
ggplot(mydata, aes(x=unique(satisfactionLevel), y = n_distinct(satisfactionLevel))) + geom_bar()
```

Comment: Did u try aggregate it until making a plot? An example: require(dplyr) data <- data%>%group_by(satisfactionLevel)%>%summarise(y = n() or n_distince what u need, then make ggplot

Comment: What is wrong with `ggplot(data, aes(satisfactionLevel)) + geom_bar()`

Comment: nothing really cheers

Comment: And what is your problem ?

Comment: that i didn't know that ggplot(data, aes(satisfactionLevel)) + geom_bar() was the answer

Comment: i am not ggplot2 seasoned enough i guess

Answer (score 0):

I think the following one should work:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = satisfactionLevel)) +
         geom_bar()
```

That counts the number of each `satisfactionLevel`.